# CodeIgniter Possible to Show MySQL Query in Error Log?

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

I always end up with errors in my CodeIgniter log such as

```
ERROR - 2011-04-12 00:06:44 --> Query error: Duplicate entry '1391280167' for key 1
```

But it's not much help without context. Is there any way to record the query as well that caused this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took a quick peek inside the `system/database/DB_Driver.php` (line 323) file and it doesn't log the SQL query with any settings you choose. It should however print these messages to the screen if you are in db_debug mode.

If you don't mind messing with the files in the CI system folder, you could get the sql statement in your log file by changing `system/database/DB_Driver.php` (line 323, for CI 2.0.1) to:

```
log_message('error', 'Query error: '.$error_msg. ' - '. $sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a start, you can get the last query that was run using **$this->db->last_query()**

---

So we could get the query as a string with the following snippet:

```
// strip out line returns, new lines and tabs
$query = str_replace( array("\r", "\n", "\t"), '', trim($this->db->last_query()) );
```

Once you have a string, we can log to the error log:

```
error_log( "Last database query: " . $query );
```

**Note:** Depending on your application logic and traffic, this could add tons of extra bloat to the error log over time, so I would recommend this is only used as a temporary troubleshooting tool.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have defined Auto Increment for the Primary Key, in the table in which you insert.

Comment: I have not. I have many tables with many UNIQUE indexes, so it's difficult to find it. Being able to see the query would make things **tons** better.

Comment: Set your error reporting of Codeigniter to E_ALL and make sure the db_debug in database.php file is set to TRUE.

Comment: Check this extension for CI error handling: http://hg.dhorrigan.com/codeigniter-uhoh/src

Comment: I have E_ALL and db_debug enabled, but the query does still not show. Thanks for the link to the extension Marko, this is a possible solution. Is there no native way to get this functionality though?

Comment: @Marko Aleksić: the link is dead